# commented out routes are rendering views

Tags: php, laravel, routes

i have all my routes commented out and its somehow rendering.

```
//   dd("hi");
//   return view('posts', [
//     'posts' => Post::all(),
//     'categories' => Category::all()
//   ]);
// });

// Route::get('/posts/{post:slug}', function(Post $post) {
//   return view('post', [
//     'post' => $post,
//   ]);
// });

// Route::get('/categories/{category:slug}', function(Category $category) {
//   return view('posts', [
//     'posts' => $category->posts
//   ]);
// });

// Route::get('/authors/{author:username}', function(User $author) {
//   return view('posts', [
//     'posts' => $author-[enter link description here][1]>posts
//   ]);
// });
```

I was having trouble starting up my server `php artisan serve` so i had to run `composer update` and now something is messed up. [video for reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/chF2L.jpg)

Comment: please use `php artisan route:list` and add the resutls to your question.

Comment: Try a `php artisan route:clear` followed by a `php artisan route:cache`

Comment: Try adding an `exit;` and see if it renders i.e. a blank page. Might make sure you're editing the right project, it can happen... and also saving.... too much phpstorm can create the habit of not saving, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Try a php artisan route:clear followed by a php artisan route:cache did the trick. Thanks simon K